# Which is best place to write common codes Static Helper class or Base Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, base-class

I have to write large amount of code which is going to be used in three asp.net pages.

I want to know the key points so that I can decide whether I should create Static Helper class , or create base class for common codes.

I am agree that creating single helper class vs creating multiple helper classes must be a careful job depending on various things like performance etc.., but the question still remain same , you can think me as a smart coder that can create perfect number of helper classes.

I think I am going to use these code only from these three asp.net pages.

Thanks for all your answers friends, but I need more inputs, can you please send more specific points.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a God object to me (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). I hope you're not suggesting creating a single static class called `Helper` and throwing all of this "common" functionality in it.

Comment: It all depends on what the code does and what the relationship of the pages is. You could go with a helper class (static or not) or inheritance or maybe even something else. To get a proper answer you need to give more information really.

Comment: I am not going to create single static helper class or God object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is code that is being shared by all three ASP.NET pages and not by other code, a baseclass is a good idea.

The code is not exposed to the 'outside world' (by making the methods protected) and you define a context in which the methods should be used. They can only be called from an ASPX page that defines trough inheritance that it is-a certain base type where the methods make sense. A Helper method could be called from everywhere in your code by just passing the right parameters, even if this is conceptual invalid.

If it's code that's going to be called from different places (for example a ValidateEmail function) then a static helper class could help.

But if you opt for the helper class, you still have to decide how many helper classes you are going to create. Dumping all your helper functions in one class is probably not a good idea from maintenance perspective.

Comment: MasterPage might work well if the pages look alike as well. In any case, this can get tricky when you have a page with "layers" of functionality - Page A that needs to be a WhoozitPage, Page B that needs to be a DingleHopperPage, and Page C that really needs functionality of both except that you can't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: Since multiple inheritance isn't an option indeed, you should then move it to a separate helper class because 'not all three ASP.NET share the code'. Only two of them intersect

Comment: oh, I think I am still not clear on this, lets suppose I am not going to use them from any other page except three asp.net pages, still base class vs helper class stands same for me.

Comment: Then it would choose for a base class as stated above.

Comment: can you explain in more detail why to go for base class in that case?

Comment: I understand that by using base class , methods will not be exposed to outside world. another question in my mind is while compiling the project does compiler merge base class merge with derived class and thus it will make all three aspx dll bulky?

Comment: If the base class is in Dll A and the other three ASPX pages are in three seperate dlls, B,C,D then BCD will reference A and when deploying the A assembly will be deployed next to BCD. They won't be merged or something, just deployed together.

Answer (score 1):

Create a base page and inherit from that and then put your helper method and properties on the base page.

Comment: If you are preferring to write code on base page then why should I move those code to helper and call helper from base page? as the code is not going to be used again, so why not to write it only on base page?